# putting php function in template works but putting concatenated function in functions.php doesn't?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here are two functions I'm working with (line 1 and line 33): http://pastebin.com/GWCJGS1i

If you notice around line 123, I have included the concatenated function `. fb_comment_count() .`. For some reason, this produces an incorrect comment count. It just shows zero no matter how many comments there are.

However, if I insert `<?php echo fb_comment_count(); ?>` into a page template, it works fine. Why does this happen? How can I get the correct comment count to show up with the concatenated function?

Here is the page template:

```
            <?php get_header();?>

            <section id="content">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <section class="entry">
                            <?php echo fb_comment_count(); ?>
                            <p class="attachment"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'medium' ); ?></p>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <?php if ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ) the_excerpt(); // this is the "caption" ?>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                </article>

            <?php comments_template(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <p>Sorry, no attachments matched your criteria.</p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            </section>

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes:

1. The global $post variable is not set when you call your function from functions.php but it is when inside the template.
2. The call to get_posts() is trashing the $post global.

Comment: I posted the page template. Does this help narrow down the problem?

Comment: Have you done an echo or other debug to check the value of $post inside your fb_comment_count() function? You template snippet proves that your function is inside "The Loop" there so $post will be present, don't know about when you call your add_filter( 'gallery' ) code though.

Comment: No, can you explain how I'd do that? I am still quite an amateur.

Comment: Inside your fb_comment_count() function you are using $post->ID and I suspect that that var is not intialized in one instance so you could add a line after $posturl = get_permalink($post->ID); to echo it out to check it has the expected value, something like: echo "id = " . $post->ID

Comment: I did that and it generated this: `id = 818id = 818id = 818id = 818id = 818id = 818id = 818id = 818`

Comment: Seeing how all of the ids are the same, I'm guessing #1 was the cause. If that's the case, how would I set the global $post variable so I can call the function from functions.php?